# BufferedImage não aparece na tela

Tags: java, swing

Estou aprendendo Java e estava precisando usar BufferedImage, mas por algum motivo este parece não funcionar

O Erro é que o desenho não aparece no panel, segui vario tutorias mas ainda sim não da certo, não sei qual pode ser o problema

```java
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

    public class App extends JFrame{



        public App() {
            super("Buffered Test");
            add(new Pane());
            pack();
            setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);    
            setVisible(true);       
        }



        public static void main(String[] args) {

            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {
                    new App();
                }   
            });
        }

    }



    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Dimension;
    import java.awt.Graphics2D;
    import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

    import javax.swing.JPanel;

    public class Pane extends JPanel {

        private BufferedImage img;
        private Graphics2D g2d;

        public Pane() {
            img = new BufferedImage(App.WIDTH, App.HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            g2d = (Graphics2D) img.getGraphics();


            draw();
        }


        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(600, 400);
        }

        public void draw() {
            g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g2d.drawRect(10, 10, 200, 200);
        }

        public void paintComponent(Graphics2D g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
        }

    }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Quando rodo o programa ele apenas aparece o Frame, imaginei que seja algum problema na hora de chamar o paint
Este é todo o código

Comment: Certo.. E qual é a dúvida? Aonde dá erro?
Uma dica importante aqui: facilite a vida de quem está disposto a te ajudar.. De TODOS os detalhes possíveis, caso contrário, dificilmente alguém abrirá mão do seu tempo para realizar análises alheias.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica O Erro é que o desenho não aparece no panel, segui vario tutorias mas ainda sim não da certo, não sei qual pode ser o problema

Comment: E no console, não apresenta nenhum erro?

Comment: Nada, o console fica vazio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está criando uma instância nova do tipo Graphics2D, quando na verdade deveria obtê-la através de uma fornecida pela implementação. Como? Através do comportamento paintComponent();

Repare porém, que o método paintCompoment() não sobrescreve o método da classe base JPanel(que herda de JComponent), pois, para que isso ocorra, precisa que esse método sobrescrito na sub classe, contenha a mesma assinatura e tipo de retorno.

Veja como é assinatura correta:

```java
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
```

e veja como está a sua

```java
public void paintComponent(Graphics2D g)
```

Para evitar esses equívocos(escrever nome errado, assinaturas e retorno diferentes), procure utilizar a anotação @Override, no método que pretende sobrescrever, pois assim, obterá erro em tempo de compilação, caso o método que pretende sobrescrever, não corresponda nas classes herdadas.

Dito isso, altere sua classe, para que ela utilize a referência controlada pelo Swing, injetada no método paintComponent. Alterando brevemente seu código, ficaria algo como isso:

```java
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class App extends JFrame {

    public App() {
            super("Buffered Test");
            add(new Pane());
            pack();
            setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);    
            setVisible(true);       
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {
                    new App();
                }   
            });
        }

    }

    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Dimension;
    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.awt.Graphics2D;
    import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

    import javax.swing.JPanel;

    public class Pane extends JPanel {

        private BufferedImage img;

        public Pane() {
            img = new BufferedImage(200, 200, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        }


        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(600, 400);
        }

        public void draw(Graphics g) {
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g2d.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
        }

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            // Referencia compartilhada.
            draw(g);
        }

    }
```

Veja, não entrei em outros detalhes(altura, largura da imagem), apenas usei seu exemplo para demonstrar sobre como deve usar a referência compartilhada.

Comment: Valeu msm, era bem isso que precisava, muito boa explicação